# É possível gerar um arquivo JSON com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Eu havia feito um projeto em PHP que lidava com dados JSON, onde eu podia criar novos arquivos com dados ou sobrescrever os já existentes. Agora desejo refazer o projeto utilizando JavaScript, entretanto não encontrei nenhuma forma de gerar/criar/sobrescrever um arquivo JSON. Apenas aprendi como abrir um arquivo JSON e armazenar seu conteúdo em uma variável e editar o conteúdo. Mas depois de o código fazer as alterações nos dados, quero exportar eles novamente para o arquivo JSON. Posso fazer isso utilizando JS, AJAX ou algo do tipo? Ou apenas PHP mesmo?

Comment: Queres fazer isso no lado do cliente ou usando Node.js no servidor?

Comment: Você deve usar [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) e o módulo [`fs` (sistema de arquivos)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) para isso, já que não é possível interagir com o sistema de arquivos diretamente pelo JavaScript do lado do cliente.

Comment: @LuizFelipe HTML 5 tem uma api pra escrever dados no armazenamenro do navegador. Mesmo em versões anteriores você pode escrever em um blob e servir como arquivo, ou salvar dados em um cookie.

Comment: Mas gerenciar (como editar) os arquivos de um computador não (como arquivos da sua área de trabalho). Isso seria um pouco prejudicial a segurança. API's como o _localStorage_, File, Blob ou até mesmo os Cookies não representam uma habilidade de interagir diretamente com o FS.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, liguagens executadas no navegador **não** podem mexer em nada fora do navegador, por exemplo, gerenciar arquivos, tudo que está disponível para uso é o que o navegador permite

Então se você quer criar um sistema que salve os dados de forma persistente em arquivos JSON, você deve usar um servidor, uma opção, já que quer usar JavaScript é o NodeJS, que executa o JS no lado do servidor, claro com algumas funcionalidades e mais e outras a menos. Se usar ele pode gerenciar arquivos com a biblioteca [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) (não vou colocar exemplos de uso, porque tem algumas formas diferentes de fazer as 4 operações - criação, leitura, escrita e exclusão)

Existem alternativas, caso não queira ou não possa ter um servidor:

- Usar o armazenamento **local** ([LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage), [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) ou [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)), ou seja, a alteração é feita apenas na máquina que realizou essa alteração.
- Usar um BaaS (backend as a service), por exemplo, o firebase, que possui um banco de dados NoSQL em tempo real bem simples de usar, basta adicionar os scripts das APIs que a ferramente fornece no seu HTML e fazer as mudanças através deles

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer isso criando um API em Node.js usando o filesystem com apenas um require('fs'), você só vai precisar installar o node no seu servidor amigo, espero ter ajudado.